# Produce a complete list of ports from a switch's VLAN configuration output in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, switch, vlan, combine

I have a set of three formulae that convert a list of ports from a switch's VLAN assignment output into an array that spills into the cells below, and I'd like to combine them into a single formula (don't know much VBA, so I'd like to keep it within existing formulas). Here's how it works.

Example data in A3:    `A1-A10,B20-B22,C12,D15-D17`

(note the text string may include both a normal space and a CHAR(160), thus the TRIM + SUBSTITUTE below)

This formula simply splits the comma-separated values into individual cells, but also removes leading whitespace.

A5 `=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(160),)),","))`

Result:

```
A1-A10
B20-B22
C12
D15-D17
```

Further, I've developed the below catastrophe to print all ports described in each of the cells produced by the above formula:

`=IF(A5="","",TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A5)),LEFT(A5)&SEQUENCE(RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-FIND("-",A5)-1)-MID(A5,2,FIND("-",A5)-2)+1,1,MID(A5,2,FIND("-",A5)-2)),A5)))`

IF makes sure an empty source cell produces a blank result cell,
TRANSPOSE converts the column range into a row range, allowing the formula to spill right
IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-"... checks if the cell includes a range by searching for a hyphen/dash, returns A5 itself otherwise
LEFT(A5)&SEQUENCE(... takes the letter from the beginning of the cell value and produces a sequence of ports based on the difference between the second and first port numbers, plus 1 (17-15=2, 2+1=3).

This formula (copied down for several rows to ensure I cover even very diverse VLAN assignments) produces an array of individual values which looks like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10
B20 B21 B22                         
C12                                 
D15 D16 D17
```

Then I use the below formula to "flatten" all the values into a single column:

`=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,AB5:AY20),",",,TRUE))`

The resulting array looks like this:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
A10
B20
B21
B22
C12
D15
D16
D17
```

I'd like to combine the three formulas, so that with a single formula pointing to the example data is expanded into the single column of all the included port IDs shown above.

How would I combine these formulas to accomplish that, or how would you create a formula to accomplish the same task more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these addresses resemble cell addresses, it seems that a solution with UDF would be much simpler. Consider such a code:

```
    Function ListA(data As String)
       Dim rng As Range, i As Long, res() As String   ' declare variables
       data = Replace(data, Chr(160), vbNullString) ' remove non-breaking spaces
       data = Replace(data, "-", ":")   ' convert e.g. A1-A10 to A1:A10
       ReDim res(1 To Range(data).Count, 1 To 1)    ' define structure of
   '      the array: 1st dimension from 1 to number of cell addresses, 
   '      2nd dimension is necessary to get a column, not a row
       For Each rng In Range(data)     ' loop for each cell
          i = i + 1                    ' increase counter
          res(i, 1) = rng.Address(0, 0)   ' populate resulting array
    '         element with a cell address without $
       Next rng
       ListA = res     ' assign the resulting array to the function result 
    End Function
```

In a sheet you enter
`=ListA(A3)`
to get a vertical list of addresses.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm very inexperienced in VBA, so I'd like to understand better what the code is doing. Could you walk through the lines and explain what each does?

Comment: Comment added to the code.

Comment: Thank you, @MGonet. Although I don't fully understand the code even now, I think this solution is the simplest. For better or worse, nesting formulas as deep as I often do is a very complex solution to a relatively simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic lambda module I developed last year for this kind of problem.

Here's a link to the gist which you can import in the Advanced Formula Environment tool found in the Excel Labs add-in. Alternatively, you can create the LAMBDA functions as names in the Name Manager (though this is a tedious process).

https://gist.github.com/ncalm/ef7ed953571eec1475c291948aa2dbc3

Per SU rules, here's the code as well:

```
/*
array is a column of stuff to which we want to apply element function
row_function is some function that produces an array with a fixed number of columns
  the column count produced by row_function must be identical regardless of input
stack_function is one of V or H

If you're unsure how these work or why we would use them, please review these videos:
https://youtu.be/04jOeiMypXw
https://youtu.be/wEBLT9QfQRw

*/

V = LAMBDA(one, two, VSTACK(one, two));

H = LAMBDA(one, two, HSTACK(one, two));

STACKER = LAMBDA([stack_function],
    LAMBDA(row_function,
        LAMBDA(array,
            LET(
                _stack_function, IF(ISOMITTED(stack_function), V, stack_function),
                seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)),
                firstrow, row_function(INDEX(array,1,)),
                reducer, REDUCE(
                    firstrow,
                    DROP(seq, 1),
                    LAMBDA(acc, curr,
                        LET(thisrow, INDEX(array,curr,), _stack_function(acc, row_function(thisrow)))
                    )
                ),
                reducer
            )
        )
    )
);

VSTACKER = STACKER(V);

HSTACKER = STACKER(H);
```

This is how you would use it:

Create a function that processes a single row of the form {from}-{to}, such as:

```
CreateVLANRange=LAMBDA(x,
    LET(
        parts, TEXTSPLIT(x, "-"), 
        fromText, INDEX(parts,1,1), 
        toText, INDEX(parts,1,COLUMNS(parts)),
        getNum, LAMBDA(x, MID(x,2,LEN(x))),
        fromNum, getNum(fromText),
        LEFT(fromText)&SEQUENCE(getNum(toText)-fromNum+1,,fromNum)
    )
);
```

Then, assuming you have imported the stacker code into a module called STACKER:

[image]

You can use this formula to process an input string into a single column of ports:

```
=LET(input, A3,
arrayToProcess, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(input,CHAR(160),),,",")),
STACKER.VSTACKER(CreateVLANRange)(arrayToProcess))
```

[image]

This may seem very long-winded, but this process of defining a row function and passing it into VSTACKER is a common problem I've seen.

You're welcome to watch the videos linked in the gist and I'll answer any questions you may have about it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @FlexYourData! I didn't know about LET prior to your answer (it's something I've needed many times before), and while I've learned a bit about LAMBDA, it's still pretty foreign to me. I appreciate the detail and background in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative way using Recursive <kbd>REDUCE()</kbd> <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(160),)),,","),
     DROP(REDUCE("", a, LAMBDA(b,c, VSTACK(b, LET(d, TEXTBEFORE(c&"-","-"),
     e, TEXTAFTER("-"&c,"-",-1), f, LEFT(d), g, RIGHT(d, LEN(d)-1),
     h, RIGHT(e, LEN(e)-1), f&SEQUENCE(h-g+1,,g))))),1))
```

---

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a formatting issue with your code block; it shows Greek characters (α, δ, ω, φ, Δ) instead of the letters you put in the formula in your GIF.

Apart from that, the variables not defined in the LET formula confuse me. For instance, "a" is defined in the LET formula first, but then you use a number of other names/variables (b, c, d) that don't seem to be defined. How does that work?

Comment: The formula is still working on my end even if i change the variables show me a screenshot how it is not working for you. Also it looks like you are not aware of using `REDUCE()` function earlier, then u should read the `MSFT` Documentations at least. And `b`,`c`,`d` etc are defined correctly as per the functions states. Read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-function-42e39910-b345-45f3-84b8-0642b568b7cb)**. Also, here `b` is my initial value the accumulator which has been taken as `""` while `c` is the value. Rest of the variables are defined along with the functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more version of the DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK method, using some alternative functions and techniques to extract the necessary variables:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("", TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(160),)),","), LAMBDA(v,n,
   LET(m, REPLACE(TEXTBEFORE(n,"-",,,,n),1,1,),
   VSTACK(v, LEFT(n)&SEQUENCE(REPLACE(TEXTAFTER(n,"-",,,,n),1,1,)-m+1,,m))))),1)
```